# how to add not equal to filter in https URL

Tags: api, jsp, url, filter

There is a URL like:

```
 https://example.com/account/sample?filter[id]=123&sort[date]=desc
```

I need to add another field `status` whose value is anything but `draft`.

I tried below ways :

```
  https://example.com/account/sample?filter[id]=123&sort[date]=desc&filter[status][ne]=draft

  https://example.com/account/sample?filter[id]=123&sort[date]=desc&status!=draft

  https://example.com/account/sample?filter[id]=123&sort[date]=desc&$filter=status ne 'draft'

   https://example.com/account/sample?filter[id]=123&sort[date]=desc&filter=status%20!%3Draft
```

Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The answer to your question largely depends on how the web page or service is handling the query string.

Comment: @ecain That is the attempted method in example#2

Comment: Are you the one writing the server or visiting this URL?

Comment: @ElanHamburger - I am writing the server part to form the query in order to make the API call